# DT_NTEXT to DT_STR Conversion

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, msbi

I have a field JSONStructure which has NT_TEXT Data Type and have to do a replace function on that.But, It looks like I cannot do a replace function on column having    DT_NText DataType. I tried using Data conversion in SSIS But my JSONStructure can have more than 8000 characters and It is not working.

Can someone suggest me the best way to do it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a Script Component, acting as a Transformation, and you'll need to specify that the column is read/write and then use C#/VB.NET string methods to perform the string manipulation